# Adding types when using tfjs-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I would like to install the types when using `tensorflow/tfjs-node` as I'm using Typescript.

I installed it via `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node`

But non of them are working to install the typings:

```
npm install --save @types/tensorflow/tfjs-node
npm install --save @types/tfjs-node
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install the types separately as they come already [bundled with the main repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node/blob/6a96dd30d5c0377a48829272a06fe31789acbcc5/package.json#L5).

To remove the old typings from `@types/...` use `npm uninstall`. After that, When using TypeScript and importing the data via `import` it should automatically pick up the correct types.